# Начальное положение скролла

Tags: javascript

подскажите как задать начальное положение скролла в JS , именно когда элемент появляется сразу на странице , чтобы указать начальное положение его скролла. Именно элемента а не глоабльного window

Answer (score 3):

Для установки конкретного положения скролла - Вы можете воспользоваться `ScrollTo`

Пример:

```js
    window.onload = function() { // При загрузке страницы
        let div = document.getElementsByClassName('show'); // Получаем элементы с классом show
        div[0].scrollTo(0,100); // Скролл первого элемента данного класса прокручиваем до нужного положения
    }
```

```css
    .show{
        overflow: scroll;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: #003eff;
    }
```

```html
<div class="show">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diem
    nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut lacreet dolore magna aliguam erat volutpat.
    Ut wisis enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tution ullamcorper suscipit
    lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
</div>
```

Постарался добавить комментарии для понимания работы скрипта.

Чуть подробнее почитать по [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo) Вы можете почитать по указанной ссылке.

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop

Указать начальное положение в количестве пикселей от верхней границы через свойство scrollTop